# Consuming a Quiz web service with C#

Tags: c#, web-services, loops, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a Quiz web service using C# in Unity 3D. I am relatively new to C#.

I've ran into a problem that I cannot seem to fix on my own. I am able to retrieve all of the questions and possible answers from the database at once. My problem is that I cannot split them up and display one question and set of answers at a time.  I am not sure how to go about this!

Here is my method which calls the web service:

```
public void retrieveQuizObject(){

    QuizService service = new QuizService();

    quizModel q = new quizModel();

    quizModel[] quizArray = new quizModel[3];

    List<quizModel> quizList = new List<quizModel>();

    //consuming web service
    object[] qArray = quizList.ToArray();
    qArray = service.playQuiz();


    foreach(object element in qArray)
        {
        quizArray[n] = (quizModel)element;
        Debug.Log ("Array Size: " + quizArray.Length);
        Debug.Log ("Questions: " + quizArray[n].question);//just checking to see questions returned
        }
  }
```

Here is the web service SQL:

```
"SELECT * from quiz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3"
```

The quiz table has the following columns: QuizId, Question, Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, Answer D.  Answer A will always be the right answer.  I plan on shuffling them later!

Using a GUI interface,  I want to display each question and the four possible answers one at a time instead of all at once (like WHO WANTS TO BE A MILLIONAIRE). When the user chooses their option, a new question should appear. I have tried many variations of loops and tried to iterate through the loop only when a GUI button is pressed but could not figure it out.

How should I approach this? Which loop should I use and how do I pause it?

I would really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: You should use a ORM framework like LINQ-2-SQL or Entity Framework to map database tables to C# objects which will make your life a lot easier

Comment: Also you need a using clause around your service reference.

Comment: If you pick a random 3 rows, won't your players have a chance to get the same question multiple times in a single session?

Comment: Hey asawyer,  No I don't think so.  I have tested it dozens of times and the rows haven't repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above code is your goal in a pseudo form, or if you actually have the service/client working, if not, seems you need to setup a framework first before you get into the specifics of Table Design and Game Mechanics.

I would start building a framework around Web API, they are pretty straight forward if you follow a few good tutorials.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Then for persistency, you can use use Entity Framework if you are going with SQL, or a NoSQL solution might make more sense such as Redis:

http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/05/12/Redis-Tutorial-with-ServiceStackRedis.aspx

Once you have your end points exposed, you will use WWW to consume it in Unity3D

The following is what I use to instantiate a game object as a packet, which will self dispose when its finished, you pass in a callback function that receives a string so you can handle your response asynchronously.

```
class CoroutineServiceAsync : IServiceAsync

{

    public void SendRequest(string url, Action<string> callback, string data)

    {

        Debug.Log("Sending service call with data: " + data);

        GameObject obj = new GameObject("ServiceCall: " + data);

        CoRoutineRequest packet = obj.AddComponent<CoRoutineRequest>();

        packet.SendRequest(url, callback, data);

    }

}



class CoRoutineRequest : MonoBehaviour

{

    void Start()

    {

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    }



    public void SendRequest(string url, Action<string> callback, string data)

    {

        StartCoroutine(StartSendRequest(url, callback, data));

    }



    IEnumerator StartSendRequest(string url, Action<string> callback, string data)

    {

        WWW www = new WWW(url + "/" + data);

        yield return www;



        if (callback != null)

            callback(www.text);



        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

}
```

You would get a Question and Answer row after the player answers or starts. If you don't want the answer options to pop up all at once, then as you are looping/iterating through the answer options, you would have a delay.

I think the only loop you need is for displaying the answer options, the rest is event driven based on player input (when they select an answer) and when the Question and Answer row packet comes in with your call back (that will trigger the data to be displayed in your GUI).

Depending on what king of security you want, you might want to handle some of the logic server side, and thus would require managing sessions. I would start simple and assume the player is playing nice.

Hope I understood the question correctly and that lends some help.